# Counting with the Alphabet

Tags: excel, vba, radix, alphabetical

So I have a range of cells that I'd like to copy paste and then change the values of several of the cells within them. I'd add a picture of the section but I don't have enough reputation yet... But basically it's 1-5 going down on the left, and A-E in a row on top going to the right.

So right now, I use this code to copy paste them and then change the letters to the next 5 in the alphabet.

```
Range("B9:G16").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. "
Range("C19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. F"
Range("D19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. G"
Range("E19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. H"
Range("F19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. I"
Range("G19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. J"
Range("C25").Select
```

This macro is assigned to a "Add 2nd Section" button. An "Add 3rd Section" button does the same thing, just shifted down and five letter forward in the alphabet.

```
Range("B18:G25").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B27").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=7
Range("C28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. K"
Range("D28").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. L"
Range("E28").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. M"
Range("F28").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. N"
Range("G28").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seg. O"
Range("K25").Select
```

I would love to just simplify this into one button that just counts the cells, shifts the copied section down, and automatically changes the letters to the next five in the set. This way you could add as many sections as you want without me having to add a bunch of buttons for each section.

I know there's a way to use Base26toBaseLetter, and I'd be more than happy to get rid of "Seg." and just have the letter in that row. I'm befuddled with the syntax.

**Note:** There are formulas in the bottom row that calculates the average. I need that to remain in the new sections as well.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You could use `ASC()`. Feed this your letters and it will return the ASCII character number. For instance `ASC("A")` will return 65. `ASC("a")` will return 97. You should be able to create logic with that.

Comment: Look at using `.Column`,`.Row` and `.Offset` or something along these lines `split(format(range("x225").Address(true,false)),"$")(0)`

Comment: Along with `Asc`, you probably will also need `Chr` - to convert the ASCII code back to a letter.  (E.g. `Chr(5 + Asc("A"))` will give `"F"`.)

Comment: Apologies, my comment should of read `split(format(cells(y,x).Address(true,false)),"$")(0)`